# How to identify if a Canada postal code is within a range of postal codes

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a report for auditing our Warehouse Time in transit times. This works easily for all our warehouses except the one in canada.

I have a table with a `range_start` and `range_end` and I download a file from our carrier which contains the postal code the customer shipped with.

Instead of the table the warehouse uses having each postal code written out it gives a range. Is there any way to identify if the postal code is within the range?

The tricky part about this is that Canada postal codes are VARCHAR so for example

`A0A1M0` is the range start
`A0A1M9` is the range end

Say I have `A0A1M3` the days it would take to get to customer would be the value of that row. I am told if I can't figure out I will have to go through 16,000 records and map it out myself.

Comment: Apologies, but your question is very vague.  A very quick wikipedia search of the Canadian postal codes shows that the set of codes is quite limited, therefore determining if a code is valid or not doesn't seem difficult.  Is this what you are asking?  Or are you asking how to interpret the local deivery code portion?  Or soemthing else?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Canada - hell you could data mine this page and get your tables real fast if this is what you needed.

Comment: Im trying to find out if a canada postal code falls within 2 given postal codes.